# Is it possible to configure typescript to add undefined as a posible type to optional chains?

Tags: typescript

I had a bug today that I think the type system should have been able to catch. Here is a short ilustration of what I mean:

```
  function getModel(): Model { /* ... */ }

  function processModelName(name: string) {
    return name.replace('x', 'y') // recently added code
  }

  const model = getModel(); 
  
  processModelName(model?.name);
```

The above code produces no typescript errors.

However even though it is not declared it is actually possible for `getModel` to return `undefined`. The `getModel` function is actually an external dependency so we can't change its return type but even if I could change it to `undefined|Model` when I hover over model it seems to have the type Model.

Why are we losing this type information. I would have hoped that when I call `processModelName` with the optional chaining it would complain because processModelName only accepts a string and here we have marked a possible nullish case which we have left unhandled.

How can this be configured in tsconfig.json?

Comment: You mention that ```getModel``` is an external dependency. If that function has its' return type declared as ```Model``` but might actually return ```undefined```, I would expect a TypeScript error would be thrown there. Even if you can't change its' return type, could you check if it passes TypeScript validation?

Comment: @Jelmer I just checked and the external dependency is correctly typed, it's just that the undefined result is getting ignored due to typescript settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had strict mode disabled in my `tsconfig.json`. I was able to catch this error and a bunch of others by enabling the flag.

It is also possible to catch only these errors by settting `strictNullChecks` to `true`, while setting `strict` to `false`.

Comment: strictNullChecks https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig